# Gradle to load Groovy 3 library

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I am using these lines to add groovy 3.0.3 library to the project. I didn't like the hard coding the path in `build.gradle` file. Is there a better way to include Groovy 3.0 library to the project?

```
  implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.3'    
    compile fileTree(dir: 'C:\\Software\\groovy-3.0.3\\lib', includes: ['*.jar'])
```

Thanks
SR

If I remove compile line getting this error.

```
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 7 s 310 ms
> Task :compileJava

> Task :compileGroovy
startup failed:
C:\work\src\main\groovyCheckCertificate.groovy: 2: unable to resolve class groovy.yaml.YamlSlurper
 @ line 2, column 1.
   import groovy.yaml.YamlSlurper
   ^

1 error


> Task :compileGroovy FAILED
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the `compile` line

Comment: whats wrong with normal dependency inclusion via `compile` or `implementation`?

Comment: I openned gradle project using InteliJ when I import `import groovy.yaml.YamlSlurper` class, its not finding this class. I need to add the compile line to fix the import error.

Comment: run `gradlew.bat dependencies` to see if `groovy-yaml` module is included

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/3.0.3), the `groovy-all` artefact does NOT include `groovy-yaml` module.

That means, that your dependency shall include it explicitly:

```
implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.3' 
implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-yaml:3.0.3'
```

or

```
implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.3', 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-yaml:3.0.3'
```

Comment: This did not work for me.